# Getting an error like unexpected value "name" on azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the below yaml file. I am trying to solve the issue where two deployment files set up in two different pipelines exist in a single folder and a case where one file change does not trigger other pipelines based on file changes.

For the above purpose, I have made the below change but getting an error in the pipeline **unexpected value "name"**,

and the code is below

```
.....
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - '.devops/**'

variables:
  deploymentFile: 'test-hub-deploy-dev.yml'

stages:
  - stage: Get the deployment file name
    jobs:
      - job: Get deployment file
        displayName: 'Get deployment file'
        steps:
          - name: Get the deployment file name    // getting error at here 
            script: |
              if [[ $Build.SourcesDirectory == *"deployment-folder"* ]]; then
                echo "##[set-output name=deploymentFile;]$(basename $Build.SourcesDirectory)"
              fi
            displayName: Get deployment file name
            env:
              SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
              BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
            outputs:
              deploymentFile: '$(deploymentFile)'

          - name: Deploy to test-dev
            condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['deploymentFile'], 'test-hub-deploy-dev.yml'))
            script: echo "Deploying using test-hub-deploy-dev.yml"
            displayName: Deploy to test-dev

  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    ....
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong with the above yaml code. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Your syntax is completely wrong.

Comment: sorry, I am not sure where it goes wrong

Answer (score -1):

1 - In triggers section 'include' and - '.devops/**' should be on the same identation level
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines#examples-2

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - '.devops/**'
```

2 - Same for 'stages' and '- stage: abc'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-stage?view=azure-pipelines

```
stages:
- stage: abc
```

3 - The same for 'jobs' and '- job'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs?view=azure-pipelines#examples

4 - And for 'steps'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps?view=azure-pipelines

First declare your step(script/pwsh/other) then you can assign name for it.
'script' needs to have dash in front of it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-script?view=azure-pipelines#examples

5 - Outputting variable is used when you want to get this variable from next jobs, here you have second step using variable from step one within same job.

6 - Where did you find this 'set-output'? Why not use ##vso + task.setvariable. This whole line cannot work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-the-same-job

7 - $(basename $Build.SourcesDirectory)
I suppose that 'basename' is variable, not constant string but you did not provide this infromation.
This will never work, to access variable you need to use syntax $(VariableName)
If you want to concat variables, put them next to each other
"$(basename)$(Build.SourcesDirectory)

8 - **I do not guarantee it will fully work** because there was plenty of mistakes that I could miss something.

The 'steps' section of yaml should be similar to this one

```
        steps:
        - script: |
            if [[ $Build.SourcesDirectory == *"deployment-folder"* ]]; then
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploymentFile;]$(basename)$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
            fi
          name: Get the deployment file name
          displayName: Get deployment file name
          env:
            SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
            BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        - script: echo "Deploying using test-hub-deploy-dev.yml"
          displayName: Deploy to test-dev
          name: Deploy to test-dev
          condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['deploymentFile'], 'test-hub-deploy-dev.yml'))
```